# IB NSController subclass bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings

In Mac OS X have an object that's a subclass of `NSObject` in Interface Builder, i.e., I've added an `NSObject` instance and set its class to `JDMyClass` (which is itself an `NSController subclass`). In IB I've created some bindings from some interface elements using the values property in `JDMyClass`, e.g., a text view bound to `values.anyProperty`.

According to [Nib Files documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19):

> Custom objects other than those described in the preceding steps receive an `init` message.

This means I don't ever have the opportunity to use `initWithCoder:`, which is where the information for the bindings comes from (I think). (That same document indicates which objects *do* receive `initWithCoder:` instead of `init`.

Later the same documentation indicates:

> - Bindings
>
>   - In OS X, Cocoa uses the `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` method of the source object to create the connection between it and its target object.

I was dubious but added it to my `JDMyClass` anyway, and the breakpoint is never hit, so Mac OS X isn't trying to re-establish any bindings from IB.

While I could make my `JDMyClass` a subclass of, e.g., `NSUserDefaultsController`, and set the **Shared User Defaults Controller** IB instance to my class, I don't really want to do this. It *works*, i.e., I get to `initWithCoder:`, call `super` and have all my bindings set, but it seems like a kludge.

The bindings aren't necessarily known ahead of time, and so I cannot establish them in code.

**So, how do I get the bindings set in Interface Builder to apply to my custom class when it's loaded from the Nib, when I have no idea in advance what the bindings are?**

Thanks!

Comment: I have to play around with IB, and can't for awhile.  But the eventual solution involves an `NSObjectController` object to bind to in your Nib.  I'm not sure, though, if you're wedded to the idea of having the JDMyClass archived and unarchived with the Nib, rather than having the custom object persisted elsewhere.

Comment: Using a subclass of `NSObjectController` is my backup plan. You know the "sunk costs fallacy"? That's me right now. I've wasted four days trying to solve this instead of doing the "easy" thing.

Comment: Using the Nib as an archive for objects that aren't truly controllers or views probably isn't easy. If you're using bindings, you should use core data for model persistence... that's the easy thing.  And in the Nib you describe, you'd have an object controller you could use to grab the right entity from your core data model.

Comment: Yeah, that's an understatement. What I was trying to do was _build_ a true controller from scratch, but IB doesn't seem to want to let me, unless it's already descended from a built-in true controller.